# I am trying install apache2 on my server (old computer) but getting error

Tags: xubuntu, apache2, localhost

I am trying to install apache2 on my server but getting failed to start the apache http server.

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-05-27 09:42:27 GMT; 11min ago

May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server'
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: Action 'start' failed.
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck apachectl[18426]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 27 09:42:27 Vizteck systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Comment: Is the default Apache port (TCP / 80) used by another process? `netstat -naptl | grep :80 `

Comment: @Majid can you please run this command     sudo apache2 -t . So that we can get the issue